# background image position fixed to parent element

Tags: css, background, position, fixed

I have a div somewhere on the page and I need to give it a background image that does not move when you scroll your browser window. This is my code so far:

```
#mydiv {
    float:left;
    width:540px;
    margin:40px 0px 0px 20px;
    background:url(/images/myimage.jpg) no-repeat fixed 0px 0px transparent;
}
```

The problem is that my background image is positioned relative to canvas and I need it to be positioned relative to `#mydiv` and still not scroll.

To illustrate the problem please see here http://jsfiddle.net/QPrUz/1/

In the example `#div1` looks fine but `#div2` does not show the background at all as it is positioned relative to the canvas instead of `#div2`.

Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S.
iframe is not an option.

Comment: If the background-image has been placed using a fixed background-attachment value, the background-position refers to the viewport, rather than the element’s padding box. - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Jawad's comment it's not possible using CSS. I ended up changing a background to something repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) for `fixed` says:

> This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to the viewport.

Use `scroll` instead of `fixed`:

> This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to the element itself and does not scroll with its contents. (It is effectively attached to the element's border.)

So, the full code for sticky background fixed relative to the element itself:

```css
.sticky-background {
    background: url(...) no-repeat scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, you just have to position the top/left of the background image so that div2 looks like div1.

here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/7kku4v1t/

I only changed:

```
background:url(http://i35.tinypic.com/4tlkci.jpg) fixed no-repeat;
```

to

```
background:url(http://i35.tinypic.com/4tlkci.jpg) 210px 0 fixed no-repeat;
                                                  ^^^^^^^
                                                  X     Y
```